# Trimming arbitrary amount of zeroes

Tags: python

I have a function which trims trailing decimal places from integers and converts it to a string. For example trim(1.0) outputs '1'.

this is my code:

```
def trim(num): 
     num1 = str(num) 
     try: 
         if '.0' in num1: 
             return num1[:num1:rfind('.0')]
         return num1
     except Exception: 
         pass
```

While this takes care of numbers with 1 trailing decimal places perfectly, it does not work with more decimal places (such as 2.000). Is there a way to trim all of the trailing decimal places?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.   2.000 is the same number as 2.0.  You talk about "trailing decimal places from integers" but integers don't have decimal places.

Comment: There is no such facility with internal representations.  Trimmable decimal places exist only in the string representation, such as when you print the value.  That's a matter of string formatting, which you can find with a simple borwser search.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you code is faulty. If I take your code and run this:

```
print(your_trim(1.1))  
print(your_trim(1.0566))
print(your_trim('1cm'))
```

The output is:

```
1.1  
1    <-- this is dangerous, the value is 1.0566!
1cm  <-- this is not even a number
```

As the commenters mentioned, you may be mismatching floats and integers. As the name implies, an `integer` does not have decimal places. If your goal ist to strip trailing zeros (for whatever reason) and *not* round a `float` to an `int`, you might use something like this approach:

```
def strip_trailing_zeroes(num):
     if isinstance(num, float):
         if int(num) == num:
             return int(num)
         else:
             return num
     else:
         raise ValueError("Parameter is not a float")
```

Testing the code:

```
print(strip_trailing_zeroes(1.1))
print(strip_trailing_zeroes(1.0566))
print(strip_trailing_zeroes(1.000))
print(strip_trailing_zeroes('1cm'))
```

Returns the output:

```
1.1
1.0566
1
Exception with "ValueError: Parameter is not a float"
```

As the other commenters put it, I can't imagine of a use case for this.

What you *might* be after, is trimming trailing zeros from a "string representation" of a float. For this, a simple regular expression replacement is enough:

```
# match a decimal point, followed by one or more zeros
# followed by the end of the input
print(re.sub('\.0+$', '', '2.000'))
```